TV Game show about London emergency evacuation, possibly 10 years ago
I'm looking to identify a TV show that was on, possibly 10 years ago, which dealt with how a group of people would react, and what strategy they would choose, to deal with emergencies.
As I remember it, one of the episodes involved the London Thames barrier failing and a tidal wave heading for central London. The contestants then had to choose how they would react, what choices they would make (for example, if they only had a certain amount of time, would they bother to evacuate the prison's etc). Their choices were then judged, I think, by members of the actual emergency services.
Can anyone remember what it was called?

I think you are looking for Crisis Command - Could You Run the Country?
It was broadcast in 2004 and involved a team of 3 people attempting to deal with a hypothetical crisis. One of the crises was a flood.
Not much official information (i.e. BBC have removed the page). The original page was http://www.bbc.co.uk/crisiscommand/ which still has some snapshots at the wayback machine.
Here is the text of the BBC info page from the web archive:

Crisis Command: Could You Run The Country? is a test of confidence and
  the ability to prioritise and keep calm in a tense and rapidly
  evolving situation. Britain is facing a crisis; people's lives and the
  security of the nation are at stake and tough decisions must be made
  quickly. How would you get on making difficult, moral choices against
  time?
Dramatising situations that Britain could one day face, Crisis
  Command: Could You Run The Country? gives three proven decision makers
  the chance to manage the country during a potential disaster. They
  have advice from Military, Emergency Services and Communications
  experts, but the final decisions are down to them alone. The team -
  acting as Ministers - will be confronted by dilemmas arising from the
  situation on the ground that will influence the fate of millions.
  Their objective is to work together to bring the crisis under control
  with as few casualties and as little economic impact as possible.
Specially-shot dramatic sequences, computer-generated graphics and
  tailored archive news footage create an ultra-real crisis in a
  never-before-seen television event.
The Ministers are constantly reminded of the need for rapid decisions
  and clear thinking by the presenter Gavin Hewitt. He co-ordinates the
  action and ensures that the Ministers are relentlessly aware of the
  fact that their decisions have a direct impact on peoples' lives. Each
  dilemma they face has a series of options and courses of action. Only
  one of them has been approved by a team of professional crisis
  managers as being most likely to lead to a positive result. Will the
  Ministerial team be able to work out which one it is? Will you?
Crisis Command: Could You Run The Country? examines the human element,
  highlighting the processes required to manage a crisis and the hard
  decisions that must be made in order to save lives. Will the acting
  Ministers be able to put their personal differences aside and make a
  decision based on facts and not emotions? Will they be able to
  influence their fellow Ministers to come over to their point of view?
Crisis Command: Could You Run The Country? itself is a high-tech
  representation of the Cabinet Office Briefing Room in Whitehall from
  which all major crises affecting the UK are managed. It is a busy
  control centre with information rich screens connecting to senior
  figures and correspondents on the ground, in the centre of the crisis,
  reporting developments as they happen. As the scenario unfolds, the
  outcomes of each of the decisions made are fed back into the bunker. 
The programme ends as the scenario reaches its dramatic climax and the
  team get feedback on how well they managed the dilemmas - have they
  turned a crisis into a disaster or has normality returned?

Wikipedia description:

The programme gave three people the chance to run the country during a
  potential disaster. The crises included terror attacks on London,
  flood, plague and hostage taking. Viewers were able to make decisions
  interactively at the same time as the studio players. The programmes
  were filmed in real time and edited down to one hour programmes.

locatetv has an episode guide

Season 1 Episode 3:
  Flood - One
  Gavin Hewitt guides three contestants
  given the chance to run the country during a simulated flooding
  crisis. Will they heed the advice of Air Marshal Tim Garden, Amanda
  Platell and retired police and intelligence officer Charles
  Shoebridge?


Yes! That is it. Thank you very much, it was driving me mad! Do you know where I'd be able to watch this show now? I cannot seem to find it on Youtube etc.

@Phil Unfortunately, where to find media is not considered on topic here, so if you want to find it, you'll have to do some research of your own.
